# How to capture the errors handling in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium2

i have created a framework where all the WebDriver API resides and in other project I am just calling those test cases I have created but the problem is that if anything goes wrong in the test case I would like to capture the error but instead currently I am just getting  output failed

so my question is what is the best way of capturing error messages?

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want to catch exceptions thrown by WebDriver OR are you looking to handle your test failures gracefully?

Comment: Also see if this question is in the line of yours? -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754615/exception-handling-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Do you use Assertons at all?  I do this alot in my test cases especially for debugging when writing them and often leave them in place for use later in case I get unexplained errors later on then I just uncomment, build and run the test to see what has changed

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the implementation of your "other project" I would suggest that;

- Change the external project to throw exceptions in the event of failure

  - Include a helpful error message, and some context about the current state of the method
- Implement a post-test screenshot capture

  - We've implemented a JUnit Rule which extends TestWatchMan that runs after a test completes (for any case) and captures a screenshot from the remote server (base64 encoded png) and stores it with a filename like : *ERROR-com.example.package.ClassName-myTestMethod.png* which is kept by Jenkins for later review

If you want control in a programatic manner, go with the first option, if its for context of a failure, use the second.

Preferably, use both :-)